# Adobe Illustrator layer problems

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Every time I try to create a new layer in Illustrator the new layer appears below the old layer instead of the other way round. I want to know why and how I can fix this.

Comment: How are you creating a new layer? Possible you are only making a sublayer?

Comment: Do you *actually* mean **Layers**? As in "Layer 1", "Layer 2", etc. Or do you mean **objects** as in `<path>`, `<path>`, `<group>`? By default AI creates new *layers* at the top of the layer stack, just like Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

You may be creating sublayers.

[image: New Sublayer button]

In Photoshop, to create  a layer below.. you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click on the new layer button

[image: Ctrl+Click new layer in PS]

In Illustrator it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> click.

[image: Ctrl+Alt+Click in Ai]

---

Any of these could be possible, depends how you are creating your layer.